# python geocoder for australian number not working

Tags: python, geocoder, carrier, python-phonenumber

I tried to get the geolocation coordinates of my mobile/cell phone number, I used phonenumbers and geocoder. the number information and carrier info came out good. but the location and region info are blank in the output. When I tried US numbers, they are fine. Is there any limitation of geocoder for cell phone numbers in Australia? If so is there any workaround or other packages available to return a phone's longitude and latitude? Many thanks.

```
import phonenumbers
from phonenumbers import geocoder, carrier

number = "+6104xxxxxxxx"
my_number = phonenumbers.parse(number, region='AUS')
Carrier = carrier.name_for_number(my_number, 'en')
Region = geocoder.description_for_number(my_number, 'en')
my_location = geocoder.description_for_number(my_number, "en", region='AUS')
print(my_number)
print(my_location)
print(Carrier)
print(Region)
```

Answer (score 0):

please try :

```
enter code here
```

```html
import phonenumbers
from num import number
from phonenumbers import geocoder
from phonenumbers import carrier


number = "+6104xxxxxxxx"
my_number = phonenumbers.parse(number, region='AUS')
Carrier = carrier.name_for_number(my_number, 'en')
Region = geocoder.description_for_number(my_number, 'en')
my_location = geocoder.description_for_number(my_number, "en", region='AUS')
print(my_number)
print(my_location)
print(Carrier)
print(Region)
```

Comment: Thanks for trying. There isn't Region and location information produced. Do you see the same result as I did?

Comment: Number and Carrier printed fine. Location and Region are missing. That's what I see, anything thoughts? Thanks